# StaleElementReferenceException: how to make it wait longer?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write an automated messages. The issue is, it takes a bit longer to write the message and then it gets the StaleElementReference error.

The error happened when it is trying to clear the person_title. and I think this should have longer waiting time because when I cut the message short (taking out several important details), the automation had no issue. How to fix it?

```py
# Locate search box through x_path
search_box = '//*[@id="side"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/p'
person_title = wait.until(lambda driver:driver.find_element(By.XPATH,search_box))


# Clear search box if any contact number is written in it
person_title.clear()
```

Comment: you can probably just re-get person_title element after clearing... which line triggers the exception?